# Frequency of letters in a word

Tags: c++

I am trying to count the number of apparitions of every letter in a word, and then, to mark the first half of a letter's appearances with 1, the middle ( if the word is odd ) with 2, and the second half with 3.

For example :

even number : ddaadd should be 111333

odd number :  dddaa should be 12313

This is the code I have so far ( I managed to count the frequencies of every letter in the word; for example, for ddaadd my output is : 442244 ) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{

    map <char, int> letters,letters2;
    string cuvant;
    cout<<"Scrie un cuvant"<<endl;
    getline( cin, cuvant );

for (  int i=0; i< cuvant.size(); ++i )
{
   letters[cuvant[i]]++;
}

for (  int i=0; i< cuvant.size(); ++i )
{
   cout<<letters[cuvant[i]];
}


}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: There is no question in this "question"

Comment: @NathanOliver:  Fair comment on my answer - I've deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay you got the first part. You may want to learn the debugger to see whats happening. I recommend visual studio 2015 and [tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A).

My guess is what you have to do is cut the string in half if there is letters on both side's (like if its mirrored). I can try attempt it later on but for now, try writing a algorithm that checks if there is a same character in the front and the back of the string. Keep trying and pushing.